# What is the proper notation for the indefinite integral of an area?

Tags: calculus, integration, notation, area

Im not exactly experienced with Calculus and math notation but I had question on Leibniz's notation:

If we have an equation $dy=2dx$, and we wanted to find $y$, we would take the integral of both sides:

$$y=\int{dy}=\int{2dx}=x^{2}+C.$$

From this we can see that taking the Integral $\int$ is the opposite of taking the derivative $d$ of a function, in this case $y$.
In an extremely broad sense we could say that the integral $\int$ cancels out the $d$ in $dy$. Now here's where my question comes up:

If we wanted to find the area of a 2D shape like a square, in calculus notation it would look like this right?
$$\text{Area}=A=\int{dA}$$

We are summing up the infinitesimal areas $dA$ inside the shape to find the whole area $A$. However, if we place the shape on a $(x,y)$ grid, we can also say:
$$dA=dx\times dy.$$

[image: Visualization]

The issue is, if we replace $dA$ in the equation we get $A = \int{dA} = \int{dx \times dy}$, which isn't right because to calculate $A$ we would have to integrate twice not once as the equation implies:

$$A=\int{dA}= \int \int (dx) dy.$$

But that implies that $d^{2}A=dx\times dy$ which doesn't seem right either conceptually.

I feel like I'm getting the notation wrong, or there's an identity or rule I'm missing. Maybe I made a mistake in my assumptions, I'm not sure. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  How did you get $d^2A=dx*dy$?  That's not right

Comment: How do you associate indefinite integrals to area?

Comment: @Xertz, $dA=y\  dx$.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner if $\int{dA}=\int{\int{(dx)}dy}$ then $dA = \int{(dx)dy}$ and $d^2A=dxdy$. That was my chain of logic, could you tell me where I went wrong?

Comment: @SarGe Yep, that's what I'm confused about. $dA = dxdy$ is simple to understand (for me, since area is length times width), but it doesn't really make sense to me how $dA=ydx$ equates to the infinitesimal area of the shape. Maybe an infinitesimally small slice would work better?

Comment: @Xertz, [see this](https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcS-5sIE_OZ740fYyLVDJ9ibJnx8HZqMMLvOdg&usqp=CAU) picture. The width of the strip is $dx$ but its length will be $y$ i.e. the functional value.

Comment: In $\int dA$, $\int$ means integration over an area, whereas in $\int\int dydx$, each $\int$ means integration along a length

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Ahh that makes sense. Is there a way to tell the two apart when writing it down?

Comment: I see the problem, you are thinking the integral symbol as a "function" where you can cancel each side out. I think you should think of each integral sign is paired up with a $dA$ or $dy$ and you can't cancel out both side when the $d$ is different.

Comment: Alright, thanks everyone for there explanations and help :)

Comment: I think your answer might get a better reception if framed differently. Like "why do I sometimes see $\int$ for an area instead of $\int\int$ when $dA=dx*dy$?" (By the way, $\iint$ is written \iint). There may be a lot that could be said in answer to *that* question: about different definitions for integration, the difference between an iterated integral and a double integral, etc.

Comment: I would recommend looking up double integrals from first principles and how they are related to iterated integrals.  Fubini's theorem is also of use.  I'd also recommend revisiting the fundamental theorem of calculus to clarify the relationship between integration and differentiation.  I don't really understand why this has been downvoted but I hope this helps.

Comment: Is not the correct notation is $\iint \mathrm{d}A$?

Comment: This is a question that the CURED people (now among the moderators) like: No homework, a lot of content and independent thought; and the MSE members are invited to grade the material: Is my proof correct? All in all, it well serves to make MSE a deposit of mathematical knowledge.